# creating two non-nested objects on the same text using element tree with python

Tags: python, elementtree, xml.etree, python-object

I have some text to convert from excel to xml adding the objects “Scope” and “Cue” to some parts of that text.

When object “Cue” is present, object “Scope” must be present. However, they are not nested: they can be in different parts of the text (in other words, “Scope” is not within “Cue” or viceversa). 
Both objects are created by the functions `mark_scope(value)` and `mark_cue(value)` which work fine. I am using `ElementTree` to build objects.

I am able to create an xml file that has either text marked as “Scope” or “Cue”, but not both, which is what I need.   I tried to use “and” to pass text first through `mark_scope` and then through `mark_cue` but I get the following error:

> FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
>     element = make_text(value) and make_cue(value)

Here is the section of my program that doesn't work (I don't want to post the whole program now because it's too long, but I'll be happy to do so if you need that information).

```
for row in excel_data:
    tweet = ET.Element("Tweet") 
    for key in row:
        value = row[key]
        element = None
        if key is 'Text':
            element = make_text(value) and make_cue(value)
        else:
            element = ET.Element(key)
            element.text = unicode(value)

        tweet.append(element)
    corpus.append(tweet)
```

Comment: What do the functions `make_text` and `make_cue` do? Also note that `x and y` returns `x` if it evaluates to `False` and `y` otherwise.